# How to queue the same workqueue work multiple times in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I see that when the `schedule_work` function is invoked it will not put the work task into the queue if it is already queued. However I want to queue the same task to be run multiple times even if it is already on the queue. How can I do this?

From workqueue.h:

```
/**
 * schedule_work - put work task in global workqueue
 * @work: job to be done
 *
 * Returns %false if @work was already on the kernel-global workqueue and
 * %true otherwise.
 *
 * This puts a job in the kernel-global workqueue if it was not already
 * queued and leaves it in the same position on the kernel-global
 * workqueue otherwise.
 */
static inline bool schedule_work(struct work_struct *work)
```

Comment: I think you may schedule as many works as you have on-line CPUs. Otherwise you need to consider something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Workqueue` expects every `work` structure to represent *single* "task", which is needed to be run once.

So, then simplest way to run a task several times - create new `work` structure every time.

Alternatively, as repeating the work while it is running is something *unusual* for workqueue, you may create your own kernel thread for execute some function repeatedly:

```
DECLARE_WAITQUEUE(repeat_wq); // Kernel thread will wait on this workqueue.
int n_works = 0; // Number of work requests to process.

// Thread function
void repeat_work(void* unused)
{
    spin_lock_irq(repeat_wq.lock); // Reuse workqueue's spinlock for our needs
    while(1) {
        // Wait until work request or thread should be stopped
        wait_event_interruptible_locked(&repeat_wq,
            n_works || kthread_should_stop());
        if(kthread_should_stop()) break;
        spin_unlock_irq(repeat_wq.lock);

        <do the work>

        // Acquire the lock for decrement count and recheck condition
        spin_lock_irq(repeat_wq.lock);
        n_works--;
    }
    // Finally release the lock
    spin_unlock_irq(repeat_wq.lock);
}

// Request new work.
void add_work(void)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    spin_lock_irqsave(repeat_wq.lock, flags);
    n_works++;
    wake_up_locked(&repeat_wq);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(repeat_wq.lock, flags);      
}
```

Workqueues are kernel threads too, with a specific thread function `kthread_worker_fn()`.